# Single Update query for ans

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
id Name gender 
1   a     M     
2   b     F      
3   c     M        
4   d     F
```

This is my table i want to update M to F n F to M

how to do this in one query.

Using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE myTable
SET gender = CASE
             WHEN gender = 'F' THEN 'M'
             WHEN gender = 'M' THEN 'F'
         END
```

## [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbdd2/1)

Answer (score 1):

You need a simple `UPDATE` that uses a `CASE` expression to do its magic:

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET gender = CASE gender 
                WHEN 'F' THEN 'M'  
                WHEN 'M' THEN 'F'
                ELSE '*'
             END
```